# SoapCall call a particular service from no of services available in WSDL PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap-client

I have to call a particular service from no of services available in the WSDL for eg,.

WSDL file contains these services

*var_dump($client->__getFunctions()) will print this result*

```
  0 => string 'example_1Rsp service(example_1Req $parameters)' (length=48)
  1 => string 'example_2Rsp service(example_2Req $parameters)' (length=56)
  2 => string 'example_3Rsp service(example_3Req $parameters)' (length=54)
  3 => string 'example_4Rsp service(example_4Req $parameters)' (length=66)
```

By default when I call the `$client->__soapCall('service','array('parameters' => $request_parameter)')` is targeting to the first service i.e **example_1Req**, here I need to target to **example_3Req**, so how I can target a particular service.

Comment: check object structure of `example_3Req` from WSDL

Comment: My experience of the PHP SOAP client has been it's buggy and difficult to work with, but as SOAP is built on fairly common standards that are already well supported in PHP (XML and HTTP specifically) it might in the long run be easier to just implement your own soap client instead of using PHP's

Comment: @GordonM I had implemented through xml and curl, the purpose am planning to use SOAP client is to have a _formatted request_ (using SoapVar,array,object) and _soapclient has intensive memory managment system_, Anyways thanks for you suggestion

Comment: @jagad89 Following structure found from the schema file along with other object `<xs:element name="example_3Req">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>ex Req</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:complexType>
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="BaseExReq">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>test </xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:attribute name="PolRef" type="common:typePolRef" use="optional">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>`